# How to copy site collection to another server

Tags: 2010

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to copy site collection to another server](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/52780/how-to-copy-site-collection-to-another-server)

I have a big corporate portal (on SharePonit 2010) and now I want to make a copy of it for my tests. So the problem is how make a copy of portal (maybe without documemts) from `http://server1` to `http://server2` ?