# How to copy site collection to another server

Tags: migration, backup

I have a big corporate portal (on SharePonit 2010) and now I want to make a copy of it for my tests. So the problem is how  make a copy of portal (maybe without documemts) from `http://server1` to `http://server2` ?

Comment: How about the users and the user groups and the respective permissions do they get copied over as well?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To back up a site collection, you must use the following stsadm command.

`stsadm –o backup –url <URL of the site collection> -filename <Name of the backup file>`

To restore a site collection, you must use the following Stsadm command.

`stsadm –o restore –url <URL of the site collection> -filename <Name of the backup file> -overwrite`

If you want to copy the whole web application follow these steps

1. Take the backup of the content database of web application in server1
2. create a web application on server2
3. restore the content database in server2
4. detach the content database from the web application created on server2
5. attach the new content database to new web application.

This will copy all the documents in document library. This method supports more than 2TB content database size.

Comment: Will this solution copy site collection with all content? (documents etc.) Is there a way to make copy with empty libraries? (because there are a lot of documents and other things, about 100 Gb).

Comment: yes this solution will copy everything.it will copy all the documents also.how many site collections are there in web application? do you want to copy documents also to the new site collection?

Comment: >how many site collections are there in web application
a lot..
>do you want to copy documents also to the new site collection?
If it's real I want to copy site collection with library (but empty,  without documents)

Comment: Do you want copy only one site collection or all the site collections (whole web application) to another server?

Comment: Whole web application

Comment: udpated the answer

Comment: If your copying the Site Collection from someone else, remember to change the Site Collection Administrator in Central Administration.

Comment: Could you explain how to perform the content database attach/detach process for the web application?

Answer (score 2):

There are three ways to do this

**Central admin:**

go to backup and restore section
Here you can take of site collection and restore from backup

**stsadm command**

To back up a site collection, you must use the following stsadm command.

> stsadm –o backup –url "URL of the site collection" -filename "Name of
>   the backup file"

To restore a site collection, you must use the following Stsadm command.

> stsadm –o restore –url "URL of the site collection" -filename "Name of
>   the backup file" -overwrite

**powershell command**

> Backup-SPSite -Identity "SiteCollectionGUIDorURL" -Path "BackupFile"
>   [-Force] [-NoSiteLock] [-UseSqlSnapshot] [-Verbose]

is the ID or URL for the site collection you want to back up.
 is the path to where the backup file is located.

If you want to overwrite a previously used backup file, use the Force parameter. You can use the NoSiteLock parameter to keep the read-only lock from being set on the site collection while it is being backed up. However, using this parameter can enable users to change the site collection while it is being backed up and could lead to possible data corruption during backup. To display the site collection GUID or URL at the Windows PowerShell command prompt, type the following command:

```
Get-SPSite | format-list -property id,url
```

> Restore-SPSite -Identity "SiteCollectionURL" -Path "Backup file"
>   [-DatabaseServer "DatabaseServerName"] [-DatabaseName
>   "ContentDatabaseName"] [-HostHeader "Host header"] [-Force]
>   [-GradualDelete] [-Verbose]

is URL for the site collection you want to restore.
 is name of the database server where the site collection resides.
 is the name of the content database.

If you want to restore the site collection to a specific content database, use the DatabaseServer and DatabaseName parameters to specify the content database. If you do not specify a content database, the site collection will be restored to a content database chosen by SharePoint 2013.

If you are restoring a host-named site collection, use the Identity parameter to specify the URL of the host-named site collection and use the HostHeader parameter to specify the URL of the Web application that will hold the host-named site collection.

If you want to overwrite an existing site collection, use the Force parameter.

Answer (score 0):

sharepoint-site-collection-from-one-Server-to-another-Server

[Link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/vrajas/backup-and-restore-sharepoint-site-collection-from-one-farm-to-another-farm-using-stsadm-commands)

Comment: It's almost what i need, but is there a way to copy site collection with empty libraries?

Answer (score 0):

You should then try to go with the site template option. It gives you the option to save a copy of the site without the content and restore it to a different server.

Refer to the image below:
[image]

Comment: Will it include subsites for this site?

Comment: This solution do not include subsites and have limitations on the size. [You can increase the size but still only to 500MB](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2014/02/increase-list-template-maximum-size-in-sharepoint.html). Remember: the original post refers to "big corporate portal".

Answer (score 0):

For my migration from developement environment to production I used this approach

http://ittechnotebook.blogspot.com/2013/07/how-to-move-sharepoint-2010-site.html

Comment: This site is not for promoting your own blog posts. Please add more details to your answers now and in the future!